# Convert and Inserting dict values into React hook's list

Tags: reactjs, arrays, dictionary, react-hooks

I am beginner in react and building simple React app and I am trying to set `dict` values into state's `list` from API.

The data which is returning from API is

```
["Book_1", "Book_2", "Book_3"]
```

so I am trying to convert this data into dict and insert into list. like :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Book_1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Book_2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Book_3"
  }
]
```

but When I try to insert into `state` then it is not converting into dict.

App.js

```
function App() {
   const [dictData, setDictData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("/fetch_from_db/").then((response) => {
          // ["Book_1", "Book_2", "Book_3"]

          setDictData(dictData => ({
             ...dictData,
             ...{"name": response.data}

          }))

      })
   })

   return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I run the function then it is setting state like

```
{
    "name": [
        "Book_1",
        " Book_2",
        " Book_3",
    ]
}
```

But I am expecting it to be like

```
[
    {"name":"Book_1"},
    {"name":"Book_2"},
    {"name":"Book_3"},
]
```

I have tried many times but it is still not working. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The `dictData` is an array that contains objects, and not an a dictionary object. To add items to it, use array spread. To create the objects, use `Array.map()` to generate objects from the names:

```
setDictData(dictData => [
  ...dictData,
  ...response.data.map(name => ({ name }))
])
```

In addition, since the `useEffects` doesn't have any dependencies, it would be called whenever you set the state, resulting in an infinite loop of added items.

You should probably set an empty dependencies (call one on mount), and replace the current state:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/fetch_from_db/").then((response) => {
      setDictData(response.data.map(name => ({ name })))
    })
 }, []) // no dependencies, call only on mount
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, It worked, I also understand about passing empty dependencies.